# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.ktor.client.HttpClientJvmKt"

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I have create kotlin multiplatform project for handling API.
I integrated this in my main project but I am getting following exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/ktor/client/HttpClientJvmKt;
```

I tried to add following dependencies in my main project still issue persists.

```
dependencies {
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.3.2"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.7"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.20.0"
}

packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/kotlinx-io.kotlin_module'
      exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
      exclude 'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-io.kotlin_module'
      exclude 'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module'
  }
```

Still I am getting this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you disable the instant run option

Comment: yes it is disabled @ShaluTD

Comment: Facing the same issue. But only on an armv7 device, which is officially not supported for Kotlin MPP projects. I assume that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In MPP you need to declare dependencies for each target.
For example:

`commonMain` needs to have the dependency you used above:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.3.2"
```

`androidMain` needs to have it's own dependency:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:1.3.2"
```

`iosMain` also needs it's own dependency:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:1.3.2"
```

Note the suffix of `ktor-client-xxxx`.
So my guess is, you only need to replace the dependency in your main project to `io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp` (or whichever client you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have added android and ios specific dependency also.

for android,

```
implementaion("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.2.1")
```

for ios

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.2.1")
```